# .htaccess infinite loop just on request_uri /mod

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm on localhost using UwAmp, Apache/2.2.22 PHP Version 5.3.25. Site is in virtual host. Everything worked 100% until I wanted to enforce no trailing slash policy. Policy words oddly:

```
# enforce no trailing/
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$   $1
```

^^ redirect match works on all requests I have tried except on `mod` or `mod/`.
example: ip:port/aaaa works, but ip:port/mod or ip:port/mod/ loops infinitly

I have disabled previous RedirectMatch and tried using pure mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Same thing. All request works as expected except /mod or /mod/

I have cleared EVERYTHING from .htaccess and left just one of these two conditions, but strange behavior remains.

First: Why is this happening? Second: Any idea how to solve it?
I'll provide additional data, just say what info you need.

edit1:
Just checked, it's the same problem on all virtual hosts with no trailing slash policy.
edit2: no, there's one site, with same settings, but no/ works even on mod :(

Comment: First, if you remove your browser's cache (or use another) you will have normal behaviour back (old permanent rules are stuck in cache). Then, with normal behaviour, is there something in `/mod` ? Is it a real directory for instance ? If so, it could be Apache forcing directory slashes (it can be disabled)

Comment: @Justin Iurman: 'been clearing cache for two days. BUT site has mod folder! You are on to something :) How to disable ` Apache forcing directory slashes` ?

Comment: Simply with `DirectorySlash Off`

Comment: Yup... That was it! But it in answer so I can accept it. Btw, now I understand why we always have RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d (if not dir check)!!! If you know, are there any downsides, dangers etc of DirSlash Off policy? Im' reading that I should use AllowNoSlash in mod_rewrite... but I'm testing it first.

Comment: Where should 'DirectorySlash Off' go? Globaly, on top of the .htaccess file or inside of <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>? Works both ways. What's better? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mod` is an existing folder, it looks like this is a directory slash problem.

With Apache, you can disable it by adding this line in your root htaccess (on the top, it's fine).

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

**But** you can also add it in `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block.
This way, it will be disabled *only* if `mod_rewrite` is enabled (which means no trailing slash because of your rule). That's the best/cleanest solution actually.

Note: I don't see any downside of using this, except maybe if you have a file (for instance, without extension) and a folder, both sharing the same name.

Comment: Do you know anything about [AllowNoSlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions)? Should I use it? So far everything is ok with just  DirectorySlash Off

Comment: Reading the doc, i would say it depends on you and what it is said in the doc. It's totally up to you

Comment: Yes... Well I don't understand what the doc's trying to say... So... probably, because I want to process all request_uris (weather I have folder or not) I should use `RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash`

Comment: `AllowNoSlash` *mod_rewrite* option allows itself to handle directories instead of passing them to *mod_dir*. In your case i guess it's useless but it can't hurt to have both

Comment: First: Thanks a million!  Second:any simple & understandable explanation is appreciated. Third: I have found [this link](http://www.lukehebert.com/2015/02/22/a-guide-to-mod_rewrite/). Forth: it works ONLY on Apache 2.4 :D I am on 2.2 :D Wondered why it didn't work :)

Comment: You're welcome. Mmmh i can't explain better than what i already told you (or even the explanation from the link you posted). Actually, if a request is made on a directory (without a trailing slash) then, by default, *mod_rewrite* delegates it to *mod_dir* in order to add the trailing slash. Since you disabled *mod_dir* `DirectorySlash` this is not a problem. You don't need it, but you can have both without crashing if that's what you want to know. Moreover, you're under 2.2 and i guess it does not exist a `AllowNoSlash` alternative

Comment: Finally understood it :)